# Network link KML on Google My Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml, google

Within Google My Maps (https://www.google.com/mymaps) There is an option when exporting the data out called:

"Keep data up to date with network link KML (only usable online)"

[image: Export options in Google My Maps]

I want my Google My Maps to update whenever I update my KML file on Google Drive and I  assume that's what the above does? But why is it on the 'export KML/KMZ' button rather than when you import the data originally?

When you click the 'learn more' button it takes you to a very unhelpful page: https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452?visit_id=636743436468746992-1430392972&p=lite_kml&rd=1

Kind regards,

Comment: would suggest to contact google https://developers.google.com/maps/support/ for official help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think MyMaps will do what you're looking for.

The "Export to KML/KMZ" dialog you are showing is for exporting *from* MyMaps, and if you select "keep data up to date...", it will give you a KML file containing a NetworkLink to the KML output of your MyMap. If you view that KML file in another KML viewer such as Google Earth, any edits you make in the MyMap will show up in Google Earth.

Unfortunately it doesn't work the other way around.  If you take the KML file you get from MyMaps and edit it, there's no way for those changes to go back to your original MyMap. Even if you upload the KML to Google Drive, the MyMap won't auto-update.  MyMaps import tool is a one-time shot.  So the only way to update the MyMap would be to re-import a KML with new/updated date.

Not sure if this is helpful for what you're trying to do, but if you were able to embed a basic map on your website using the Google Maps Javascript API, then could add a KML layer to it, with a pointer to your MyMap's KML output, and that way anytime you update the MyMap, the KML displayed on your site would update. Alternatively, you could point the KLM layer to a KML file on your server, and have it show the latest KML anytime you update that file.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a more helpful link describing Network Links

https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/learn/using-network-links-effectively/